# Real world 3D applications

Tags: wpf, silverlight, 3d

I've never seen such a thing and I'm really curious to see one.
My question is particularly on 3D app!! and real things and not just a rectangle tutorial from codeproject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few frameworks for using 3D in Silverlight. Some of them are

- [Balder](http://balder.codeplex.com)
- [kit3D](http://kit3d.codeplex.com/)
- [PostVision](http://www.postvision.net/SilverMotion/Demos.aspx)

Take a look to demos. The best example for me is 3D demo in [Silverlight Firestarter](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Silverlight-Firestarter/Silverlight-Firestarter-2010-Keynote-with-Scott-Guthrie). But that was for Silverlight 5, which is not released yet.

Answer (score 2):

There are some quite cool demos of WPF's 3d graphics on this site

http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/

this demo is also realised in silverlight 5, as a typical example of hardware acceleration. Its source code can be reached here `http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/Solar-Wind-3D-Sample-4cb56170`

Answer (score 0):

3D CAE System for Industry.
 [Screenshots.](http://www.orlovsoft.com/Silverlight.html#/Screenshots) 
It is WPF 3D application.